# Как записать в html файл код скопированного div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Как записать код копии div в html файл? С помощью этого кода делаю копию div, но скопирован div выводится только на экран и не записывается в файл html.

```
<input type='text' name='name' placeholder='название товара' value='' />
    <input type='submit' onclick="copyDiv()"/>
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/20x20/ffffff/ffffff.jpg">
      <div class="info">
        <span>Тэн 18Мм 1750Вт Kawai</span>
        <p>уточнить цену</p>
        <button>05478987488</button>
      </div>
    </div>
     <script >
    function copyDiv() {
      var src = document.querySelector(".card");
      var dst = document.createElement("div");
      dst.className = "card";
      dst.innerHTML = src.innerHTML;
      dst.querySelector("span").textContent = document.querySelector("input[type=text]").value;
      src.parentNode.appendChild(dst);
    }
     </script>
```

Comment: `copyDiv()` - выполняется в браузере на компьютере пользователя, html файл находится на сервере за тысячи километров от браузера.

Comment: То есть, нужно переписывать код под сервер?

Comment: Вы можете сохранять действия пользователя в `localStorage` и восстанавливать то, что сделал ранее, во время загрузки страницы.

Comment: Вам надо хранить информацию о товарах в базе данных, из нее брать при запросах страниц с сервера, и в нее же сохранять, когда Вы хотите добавить товар.

Comment: Эх ... Заказчику нужно чтобы без бд

Comment: @АндрейПовх можно использовать чужую бд, или по запросам с клиента менять код html на сервере, но второе это те же яйца что и бд, только в профиль и на велосипеде

Comment: Вообще можно, но это будет сильно от браузера зависить.